# 500 Error with .htaccess password protection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, passwords

I am running latest ubuntu with apache.

I have very simple html directory I want to protect using `.htaccess`.

I am trying to do it with:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/dev/docs/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

On my `.htpasswd` file I have:

```
user:pass
```

I get internal server error with this. I've been digging hard but not sure why this is happening.

If I add a this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/dev/docs">
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/dev/docs/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

I can't login no matter what I do...

Thanks,

Comment: Check your Apache `error.log`

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem. But after a few trial and error, here's the fix.

1. You must use the full path to the .htpasswd file.
2. You must encapsulate the path with quotation marks "home/username/public_html/subfolder/protected/.htpasswd"

An example:

```
AuthUserFile "/home/username/public_html/subfolder/protected/.htpasswd"
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My restricted Area"
Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 2):

Error #500 just means the web server isn't understanding something in your .htaccess file. There will be nothing in Apache's error log since the request doesn't even get parsed at this point.

Try putting quotes around the path to the .htpasswd file and note on some hosting companies like cough.. godaddy, 1&1  It may take several minutes for the changes in .htaccess to be picked up.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile "/home/. . . . ./.htpasswd"
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got same situation on Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

1. Path to htpasswd needs to be taken from  `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`
2. Apache has some bug (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54735), you need to set password from console like this:
   `htpasswd -nb username newpassw > <path-to>/.htpasswd`

btw in Apache 2.4.6 on CentOS 7 problem still exists